# how to Rollback to windows 1703 from updated windows

Tags: windows-10

recently i installed windows 1703 and forget to close update, i don't want windows 1903
but it update itself from 1703 to 1903,

**Now** the Question is>> is there anyway to rollback to windows 1703 **without losing files**?

i mean the easiest way

i tried to boot DVD and use Upgrade windows instead of format  Drive C: but it shows error
**Also I Have Windows 1703 Installation on DVD**

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Settings app, Update & Security, Recovery. Click the Get started button under Go back and see if you can go back to your prior version. You need to do this within 15 days.  (The number of rollback days was changed here).

Windows 10 for regular users (not business LTS version) will update anyway, so you cannot prevent updates permanently. Also V1703 is out of support, so the Microsoft update process may not let you go back that far.

V1903 and V1909 fully updated are working fine. So you may need to upgrade.

If rollback does not work, there is no easy way.

Comment: The amount of time is actually 15 days not 30 days with the more recent feature releases.  Important to point out that 1703 is unsupported and the author will continue to be pushed 1909.  They could prevent all updates any number of ways, and since their system would not be eligible to receive cumulative updates, there really isn’t a security concern by disabling Windows Update.  *The rollback option will be presented provided it’s within the timeframe.*

Comment: Thank you for the update about number of days. Appreciated.